# Why doesnt anything appear on the canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

This is my code:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 990;
canvas.height = 409;
canvas.style.display='block';
var style=canvas.style;
style.marginLeft="auto";
style.marginRight="auto";
var position=1;
var background  = new Image();
background.src="backdrop3.jpg";
var currentImage= new Image();

document.body.appendChild(canvas);
ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
```

For some reason, nothing appears on my html canvas. Ive already checked that the file for the background is in the same location and it is. What could be the problem?

Comment: Try adding the `width` and `height` before `canvas.getContext("2d")`.

Comment: Check this: http://jsbin.com/letuvejiji/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw the image onto the canvas *after* it has loaded, like this:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 990;
canvas.height = 409;
canvas.style.display='block';
var style=canvas.style;
style.marginLeft="auto";
style.marginRight="auto";
var position=1;
var background  = new Image();
background.src="backdrop3.jpg";

// the important bit
background.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0);
}

document.body.appendChild(canvas);
```